# Redux Form - CSS change once but not trigger new change

Tags: reactjs, validation, redux, redux-form

I would like to form a user if he had filled an input right or not dpending of some validation method. Right now I just have implemented `isRequired`.

I can add a symbole if it's correct (green) or not (red) after the first `touched`. But, for exemple, if I correct the input my icone doesn't change from red to green.

InputItem.js

```
import React from 'react';

const InputItem = ({ spec, input, meta: { touched, error } }) => {

  const successIconRight = {
    color: '#2ecc71'
  };

  const errorIconRight = {
    color: '#e74c3c'
  };

  const { label, type, placeholder, iconLeft, iconRight } = spec;

const renderIcon = () => {

  if (touched && error) {
    return (
      <span className="icon is-small is-right">
        {/* <i className="fas fa-ban" style={errorIconRight} /> */}
        <span style={errorIconRight}>NON</span>
      </span>
    )
  } else if (touched && !error) {
    return (
      <span className="icon is-small is-right">
        {/* <i className={iconRight} style={successIconRight} /> */}
        <span style={successIconRight}>OUI</span>
      </span>
    )
  }
}

  return (
    <div className="field">
      {label && <label className="label">{label}</label>}
      <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
        <input
          {...input}
          className="input"
          type={type}
          placeholder={placeholder}
        />
        <span className="icon is-small is-left">
          <i className={iconLeft} />
        </span>
        <span className="icon is-small is-right">
          { renderIcon() }
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputItem;
```

**EDIT :**
Playing around with the redux-form example code and mine I figured out that if I try to render something else than an icone `<i ... />` it's working. Here I edit my snippet with a `<span>` and it's working. But if you uncomment the icone and comment the `span` it's not working proprely... I have no clue why.

Comment: Does the render function even get called when user changes the input? What are the values of `touched` and `error`? Is that part working correctly?

Comment: Like I wrote in my edit. Everything is working well if I use a `span`. So i guess the render function is call.Seems like an `i` isn't enough to call it.

Comment: Can you post what the relevant CSS looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a case, where the two elements returned by the condition are similar and react doesn't detect a change in the virtual DOM for some reason, thus does not rerender. If this is the case you might try to wrap only one of the icons into an empty `span` to assure that the DOM is changed when the condition changes or you can try assign them different keys (`<i className={iconRight} style={successIconRight} key={1}/>` for example). Altough I am not sure this would work, but react keeps track of its internal representations using keys.

Comment: I see what you mean but why an `i` is not enough for react to render ? Also I try your suggestion and I got two erros when the icon should have change.


`The above error occurred in the <i> component:
... (and goes up to my root component)


Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.`

And 

`NotFoundError: Node was not found`

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT !!!
I just had to put the `key` props not on the `<i>` tag but on the `span` parent !!!

But just why ?

Comment: It might be a react bug, but when the condition changes the DOM tree does not as it is seen by react (probably). But since react uses keys to manage its virtual DOM, it might be able to detect changes that way.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what happen. I just posted an issue on React's git to understand if it a bug or a feature ;)